# No sound after waking up

Tags: ios, audio, mobile, air

We've been using the AIR sound API, building for iOS, with no problems till now, the problem is that the sound works until iPad goes to sleep and there's no sound from our app when iPad is woken back up.

Note: we have the app set to exit on suspend, and we don't have this problem when user suspends -- i.e, hits the button and goes back to desktop.

We only have it when iPad goes to sleep (screen goes dark but app is still running). As far as I can tell our app is not receiving any events from iOS when the iPad goes to sleep or wakes back up. Once this has all happened and the game has no sound, but exiting and restarting makes it work again.

We are getting an activate event from the native application object when iPad is woken up, I'm also checking (just because it sounds useful) the value of `SoundMixer.areSoundsInaccessible`, but that's way off base. I do get a soundchannel object back when I play a sound while the problem is in effect, I just can't hear it.

Answer (score 0):

We were having a similar problem with audio not playing (roughly half the time the device had been asleep), and fixed it with this:

```
// AudioPlaybackMode.MEDIA is the default value
SoundMixer.audioPlaybackMode = AudioPlaybackMode.AMBIENT;
```

Once that was done, audio came back immediately after the app woke up.

Note that AMBIENT's behaviour depends on [whether the microphone is being used](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/AudioPlaybackMode.html#AMBIENT).